# Data truncated when pasting worksheet into multiline field

Tags: 2007, excel, datasheet

I'm trying to paste the contents of an Excel sheet into a list in Datasheet view.  This list has several multiline columns, and the Excel data items i'm trying to paste in are quite large--in some cases, up to 35000 characters in one cell.  There are about 7000 rows of data in the sheet and 30 columns.  When I select all the data in the Excel sheet and try to paste it into the Datasheet, I get this message:

```
31879 cells could not be pasted.
Some data was truncated because the pasted data contained more characters than the destination column allows.
Do you wish to continue with the operation and accept the changes?
```

When I click "yes", I end up with truncated data in the multiline fields.  But if I copy the data, then click so that the cursor is in an individual mutiline cell, and then pasted the data, all the data for that cell is successfully pasted.

How can I paste the whole data set without it getting truncated?